# How to set up a http server while using SUMO/TraCI

Tags: python, server, client, sumo

My problem: TraCI runs in a loop and the http server as well. Because of the server loop, my SUMO simulation can't proceed.

So, I'm trying to build the TraCI part as client.
Threading not seems to be the solution because in the TraCI Doc is written, that starting a SUMO server with TraCI is not safe while using threads.

I want to put some data from the Interface TraCI (SUMO) on a http server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think multi threading is the solution here. The part in the sumo docs just refers to the fact that it is not safe to access the traci connection from several threads. As long as you make sure that only one thread is handling the traci part and he other one the webserver you should be safe. But before you try building a traci webservice you should have a look at [Traas](http://traas.sf.net/) which does the same thing.

Comment: so you're saying that it should be like TraCI client in one thread and the server in another one? how should I handle the excange of information? maybe with a queue?